# Facebook like button shows same # of likes on every page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I thought the like button was supposed to show a number of likes per page and not per site.  Am I correct?

I put the like button on my site http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com and if you look at different pages of the site, they all show the same number of likes as though it is a universal number for the entire site.

My like button code is in the header div and I suspect the repetition may be happening because of that.

Any ideas/thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [XFBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) version, which will `like` the current page if the `href` is not specified:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Thank you - the XFMBL version was just what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

hi dear its just because that you are using the same url on every page. You can set your your dynamically.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=<?php echo('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px; background-color:#CCCCCC"></iframe>
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 2):

This page will show you how to set it up so each page URL can be liked.
[Facebook reference document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem must be other, because I'm using the following

```
< fb:like href="http://tienditas.net/{{storename}}/{{productoid}}" send="true" width="320" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>"
```

Which produces a unique URL for each page "like" button, and still have the same problem about showing a universal number for the entire site.